# Rails Validations and the DRY principle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, dry

I have 9 different models, all with a column called 'name'. In each model I have the following validation:

```
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

To adhere to the DRY principle, should that validation go in a parent class and have my models that use that validation inherit from the parent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a name validation concern instead. That way if you ever want to change the validation you only have to do it in one place, without having to create subclasses of something with model behaviour that isn't actually a model.

You can read how to use Concerns here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html